# Does an external reference to a field within a struct prevent that struct from being garbage collected?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

For example, if I have some `type A struct { B string; C int }`, and I have a `func foo(a A) *string { return &a.B }`, and I call it with `c := foo(a)`, will `a` necessarily stay in context until `c` is collectible?

Or, if I define `func foo1(a A) *string { s := a.B; return &s }` will that have any effect on when the `A` can be collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, assuming `a` is not used after calling `foo(a)`, `a` is collectable, because you passed `a` by value. The function returned a pointer to a value in a copy of `a`, so `a` becomes collectable, but the copy created in the function `foo` is not collectable.

Now, if you passed `&a` to `foo(a *A)`, then `a` would not be collectable, because `c` is  a pointer to it.

The second example you give also passes a copy of `a`, so same arguments apply. However, if you passed `&a`, and then returned a pointer to a copy a string from `a`, `a` would be collectible, but not the string you returned, because there is a reference to it.

Comment: You're correct about the passing-a-by-value; not fixing in the question itself since I feel that it'd make your answer less clear in context